# Show content on a hovering div without affecting the height of div

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building up a product listing page for an ecommerce site.  For that I am using Laravel with Bootstrap 3.

I am trying to show variations of a product in same div by appending to the end of it.  However, when the data is appended to the product div, the height of div is increased. This is an unwanted behaviour. What I want is that the product variation options to show above other divs that come below the active divs.

Here is the partial code that I am trying to style:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 text-left product-tile product-tile-hovering">
<div class="product-inner">
    <div id="pid" class="hidden">3</div>
    <img src="/images/small/1444895511.jpg" alt="alt stuff" class="img-responsive">
    <br>
    <strong>Rs. 200</strong>
    <p class="product-title-tile">
        Close Up Diamond Attraction Power White Toothpaste &nbsp; 200g
    </p>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart product-tile"></span>Cart
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-blue btn-xs">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star product-tile"></span>List
    </button>
    <p class="more-variant-message">See 6 more variants</p>

    <div class="variation-options">

        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 200 / 200g</td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 225 / 250g</td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 200 / 300g</td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 150 / 400g</td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 2000 / 450g</td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 200 / 500g</td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 200 / 550g</td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 200 / 200g</td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 225 / 250g</td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 200 / 300g</td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 150 / 400g</td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 2000 / 450g</td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 200 / 500g</td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 200 / 550g</td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the css

```
.variation-options{

  // what should I apply here to make to show the variation-opionts div above other divs?
}
 .product-tile .product-inner{

}
   .product-tile{
   position: relative;
}
```

Please see the attached image.
[image: Div image]

I am stuck here for a few hours now.  Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure why the ``table class="table"`` appears twice. Seems exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the only solution, but I'd use these attributes:

```
.variation-options {
    postion: absolute;
    z-index: <greater than z-index of the elements that need to be obscured by the menu>
}
```

Relative positioning does not indeed place the element outside the normal flow, but allows displacing the element relatively to its container, with the help of attributes `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right`.

Comment: Thank you MaDa . It fits my use case perfectly. :)

Answer (score 1):

parent should  be relative and your .variation-options absolute

now take top of element example if you hover on clear button then apply top of clear button.

or
**example** : http://jsfiddle.net/miljenko/xTZ87/  i found on jsfiddle

> **you can also use bootstrap popover and apply this table html in
>   tooltip template**

see popover example http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_popover_pos&stacked=h

**your example in popover = http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/t0pmu68g/3/**

```css
.variation-options {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #B1B1B1;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 8px 1px #808080;
  top:10px
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 text-left product-tile product-tile-hovering">
  <div class="product-inner">
    <div id="pid" class="hidden">3</div>
    <img src="/images/small/1444895511.jpg" alt="alt stuff" class="img-responsive">
    <br>
    <strong>Rs. 200</strong>
    <p class="product-title-tile">
      Close Up Diamond Attraction Power White Toothpaste &nbsp; 200g
    </p>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart product-tile"></span>Cart
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-blue btn-xs">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star product-tile"></span>List
    </button>
    <p class="more-variant-message">See 6 more variants</p>

    <div class="variation-options">

      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 200 / 200g</td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 225 / 250g</td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 200 / 300g</td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 150 / 400g</td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 2000 / 450g</td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 200 / 500g</td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 200 / 550g</td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 200 / 200g</td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 225 / 250g</td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 200 / 300g</td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 150 / 400g</td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 2000 / 450g</td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 200 / 500g</td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="product-variation-tile-tr" colspan="2">Rs. 200 / 550g</td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-material-green btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Keval.  I didn't know about the popovers before.  However, MaDa's answer is better suited to my use case. Thanks anyways for help :)

Comment: @InspiredCoder   http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/t0pmu68g/3/ see i done with popover but in fiddle i will not take container so i applied template in html but below i commented javascript code for you